# Open other program's configuration files

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, configurationmanager

I have a program **A**, it also have an app.config file where I have added some keys like server address, username and password for connecting to a server. It is a console application. Now I want to make a UI which I have done. In that UI I want to modify the content of app.config of program **A**. How do I do that?

Here is what I tried, I copied the UI (basically an .exe) to program **A's** directory, where the app.config also resides. Then in the UI, I use the *ConfigurationManager* class's *OpenExeConfiguration* method, and passing the program **A's** filename as an argument. But it throws and exception of type *System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException*.

So I think that my approach is incorrect. How shall I do this?

**EDIT:** Oh I forgot to tell I'm using C#, .NET 3.5 and VS 2008 (if that helps :D)

Comment: Can you add a code sample of the call to OpenExeConfiguration, and more details about the exception?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not sure about the problem with your approach (try adding the stack trace to your post) but this is how I do it:

```
var configMap = 
    new ExeConfigurationFileMap
    {
        ExeConfigFilename = externalConfigurationFile
    };
System.Configuration.Configuration externalConfiguration =
    ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(
        configMap,
        ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

foreach (var setting in externalConfiguration.AppSettings.Settings)
{
    ...
}

externalConfiguration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
```

Comment: I think the last line should be externalConfiguration.Save rather than currentConfiguration.Save