# How do I create a Solution Wide Connection String

Tags: visual-studio, connection-string, app-config, global, solution

Does anyone know if it is possible to create a single connection string that will be accessible to all the projects in a solution (we have about 6).

I can create a text file with this information, but we need design time support as well, and it is not practical to have a connection string in every App.Config and Web.config file in the solution.

We basically want a Single connection string that is easy to change should the location of the db change, that will also be used by the IDE for design time support

Comment: Firstly, I am a delphi developer and VERY new to the .Net environment...
If I can give some more information:
We have 1 EXE, 1 web application, and numerous DLL's.  We want all the projects to be able to access these at runtime AND design time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, can't you just put a new config file to the solution items and include and load it in all projects?

Edit: I am specifically talking about a general (XML) config file, not an "App.config". Is has exactly the same format, it just goes by a different name. Add this file to your solution items and access it using [OpenMappedExeConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openmappedexeconfiguration(v=VS.90).aspx).
You can find an additional example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939074/c-configuration-files).

Comment: This does not seem possible... but i might also miss something.  As mentioned in comment above, I am quite new to .net

Comment: OK This is getting very useful now.  I have also managed to write a very similar function.  The same principle will apply.
In the Settings.settings file of our one DLL, I declared a connection string. This can be accessed in the following way for FormName.Designer.cs
this._connection.ConnectionString = global::MyDLL.Properties.Settings.Default.MyConnectionString;

The last question i have, the *.designer.cs files are system generated.  If i were the connection string in the designer.cs file, and I then make changes to the visual designer, will it delete this manual addition that I have added?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know that. Maybe just try it out? :)

Comment: OK It seems to work without any problems, well at least for now. :) 

THanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, if you don mind, upvoting an answer marks it as helpful. ;)

Comment: I tried but dont have an account, must still register.  Will do as soon as I have registered.

Comment: OK My reputation is not high enough to Vote Up yet... sorry.  If someone else could vote up on my behalf it would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't worry about it too much xD

Answer (score 1):

put the connection string in the config of your "main" project. Create a Data Access project with a connectionstring property. Set this property when you initialise your project and use the Data Access project for all database related actions in all 6 projects

Comment: That will only work if there is a main project, not if e.g. several projects each produce an .exe.

Comment: You can also but the connectionstring in the config file of the Data Access project. This way you only have it at one place

Comment: Ivo... This is basically what we tried... but i can only access it at runtime. We need design time support as well (Especially for DevXpress reports).  We are running in a postgreSQL database and use Devart's UniDirect components.